# How do I read ints and other values without needing to use Parse and Split()?

Tags: c#

I've been trying to read data types on the same line, and I have seen it used in C++ before but haven't found a way to use it in a fast way in C# like in C++.

C++ Example :

```
int s;
int y;
cin >> s >> y;

cout<<s + y;
```

How can I implement this but in C# **without** using Split() between two variables, and **without** using Parse to convert the string to an integer?

Here is a C# example :

```
string[] i = Console.ReadLine().Split(null);
int[] a = Array.ConvertAll(i, int.Parse);

Console.WriteLine(a[0] + a[1]);
```

Is there anyway to simplify this C# code, so it is similar to the C++ code, maybe without using  `Parse` and `Split()`?

Comment: What does your input data look like?

Comment: It's very simple, the user inputs two numbers and it gives them the sum of both, the thing is, I'm trying to simplify the code so it doesn't use Parse and arrays and all that, I am trying to get it to be as simple as the c++ code.

Comment: What you have is ok. If you want it all in one line: `Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(int.Parse);` Or to get the total: `Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(int.Parse).Sum();`

Comment: If you're asking if there is a way to ever get the same type of syntax as C++, no there isn't. You have an input string from ReadLine so you have to do SOMETHING to get to the point where you have integers that you can add together. There is nothing built into Console.ReadLine that will do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to overload the bitshift operator (same as the stream operator in c++)... But one method would be to just create a method that does both readline and converts the input parameters to the correct format. Like:

```
int[] nums = GetNumbersFromInput();
Console.WriteLine(nums[0] + nums[1]);
```

Comment: You may want to expand on "no way ... to achieve a similar c++ syntax". I.e. it is possible to override `operator >>` - explaining what problems one gets would make answer much better.